# XSLT for XML1 to XML2

Tags: xslt

Source xml coming from backend (XML1)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xml:lang="en-us" xsi:schemaLocation="http://naesb.org/DATA DATAschema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Patomi" xmlns:DATA="http://naesb.org/DATA">
    <id>urn:uuid:0299-467E-972A-A883ECD</id>
    <link rel="self" href="/DATA/1_1/resource/DCust/AI/1"/>
    <link rel="up" href="/DATA/1_1/resource/DCust/AI"/>
    <title>SubmitData.org  DCust Application</title>
    <content>
        <AI xmlns="http://naesb.org/DATA">
            <DCustId>Gets the value from backend</DCustId>
            <DCustAS>Gets the value from backend</DCustAS>
            <tAD>Gets the value from backend</tAD>
            <tAS>Gets the value from backend</tAS>
            <tAT>1</tAT>
            <tAU>1</tAU>
            <tAPhone>+1 800 673-6377</tAPhone>
            <AZUri>Gets the value from backend</AZUri>
            <tPNUri>https://services.Submitdata.org/TP/DATA/1_1/Notification</tPNUri>
            <scope>Gets the value from backend</scope>
        </AI>
    </content>
    <published>2014-01-02T05:00:00Z</published>
    <updated>2014-01-02T05:00:00Z</updated>
</entry>
```

Destination xml (XML2)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xml:lang="en-us" xsi:schemaLocation="http://naesb.org/DATA DATAschema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Patomi" xmlns:DATA="http://naesb.org/DATA">
    <id>urn:uuid:0299-467E-972A-A883ECD</id>
    <link rel="self" href="/DATA/1_1/resource/DCust/AI/1"/>
    <link rel="up" href="/DATA/1_1/resource/DCust/AI"/>
    <title>SubmitData.org  DCust Application</title>
    <content>
        <AI xmlns="http://naesb.org/DATA">
            <DCustId>Gets the value from backend</DCustId>
            <DCustAS>Gets the value from backend</DCustAS>
            <tAD>Gets the value from backend</tAD>
            <tAS>Gets the value from backend</tAS>
            <tAT>1</tAT>
            <tAU>1</tAU>
            <tAPhone>+1 800 073-9377</tAPhone>
            <AZUri>Gets the value from backend</AZUri>
            <tPNUri>https://services.Submitdata.org/TP/DATA/1_1/Notification</tPNUri>
            <scope>Gets the value from backend</scope>  
            <logo_uri>http://services.data.org/TP/favicon.png</logo_uri>
            <client_name>Client_TP</client_name>
        **  <client_uri>https://services.data.org/TP</client_uri>
            <redirect_uri>https://services.data.org/TP/data1/1_1/OAuthCallBack</redirect_uri>
            <policy_uri>http://services.data.org/TP/Policy</policy_uri>
            <software_id>1.00.00</software_id>
            <software_version>version 001</software_version> **
        </AI>
    </content>
    <published>2014-01-02T05:00:00Z</published>
    <updated>2014-01-02T05:00:00Z</updated>
</entry>
```

My xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="dp" extension-element-prefixes="dp dpconfig dpfunc" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dom="http://www.schema.services.customer.csbu.sce.eix.com/dom/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<!--Identity template, 
        provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Questions:

1)I am trying to write an xsl which does transformation of XML1 to XML2

2)Where do I need to add the static fields in xsl? 
Note: static fields are highlighted as **

Comment: You can read any XSLT tutorial to understand XSL basics. For example: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 0):

You already have a basic copy template in place and you only want to add nodes at the end of the `AI` node; so you can simply do this by creating a new template:

```
<xsl:template match="AI">
  <!-- create the AI node -->
  <xsl:copy> 
    <!-- copy all existing nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    <!-- add new nodes: -->
    <client_uri>https://services.data.org/TP</client_uri>
    <redirect_uri>https://services.data.org/TP/data1/1_1/OAuthCallBack</redirect_uri>
    <!-- ... -->    
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Just realized the namespace at the AI element; you might have to include the namespace in your xslt: `xmlns:data="http://naesb.org/DATA"` and then match for `data:AI`.

Alternatively you can use the `local-name()` function of xslt and match for `local-name() = 'AI'`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Got it Let me try and get back to you

Comment: ok Thanks (please see my templat match) is it correct?
  <xsl:template match="AI xmlns:data="http://naesb.org/DATA">
  <!-- create the AI node -->
  <xsl:copy> 
    <!-- copy all existing nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    <client_uri>https://services.data.org/TP</client_uri>
    <redirect_uri>https://services.data.org/TP/data1/1_1/OAuthCallBack</redirect_uri>
    <policy_uri>http://services.data.org/TP/Policy</policy_uri>
    <software_id>1.00.00</software_id>